# How do I reference and act on parent and child containers

Tags: c#, winforms

Say what you want about JavaScript, but navigating hierarchy is a breeze. Maybe C# is too, but I don't know how. I have a program with a series of controls where the control is repeated over and over:

[image: form buttons example pic]

The buttons all operate the same so I'm repeating a lot of code and it seems inefficient:

```cs
        // There's a function just like this for EVERY button
        private void FixedF1(bool isFixed)
        {
            if (isFixed)
            {
                F1FixerBtnDot.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(80, 214, 0);
                F1FixerBtnDot.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopLeft;
                F1FixerBtnArea.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.green_btn_bk_sm;
                F1FixerBtnBox.Text = "Fixed!";
                PrefMatch("KillF1Help", "yes", F1FixerBtnDot);
            }
            else
            {
                F1FixerBtnDot.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(244, 180, 0);
                F1FixerBtnDot.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopRight;
                F1FixerBtnArea.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.yellow_btn_bk_sm;
                F1FixerBtnBox.Text = "Fix it!";
                PrefMatch("KillF1Help", "no", F1FixerBtnDot);
            }

        }

        private void F1FixerBtnDot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (regStuff.F1HelpActive())
            {
                // Save the new setting
                prefs.SetPref("KillF1Help", "no");
                // Toggle it
                regStuff.RestoreF1();
                FixedF1(false);
            }
            else
            {
                prefs.SetPref("KillF1Help", "yes");
                regStuff.KillF1();
                FixedF1(true);
            }
        }
```

In the first function, I have code that turns the button "on" and "off". The operation is basically repeated for each of these buttons and I might have 30 or more. I'm trying to recode it something like this (based on how I would do this in JS):

```cs
        private void ToggleFixedButton(GroupBox which, bool isFixed, string prefName)
        {
            which.child(islabel).ForeColor = isFixed ? Color.FromArgb(80, 214, 0) : Color.FromArgb(244, 180, 0);
            which.child(islabel).TextAlign = isFixed ? ContentAlignment.TopLeft : ContentAlignment.TopRight;
            which.child(isPanel).BackgroundImage = isFixed ? Properties.Resources.green_btn_bk_sm : Properties.Resources.yellow_btn_bk_sm;
            which.Text = isFixed ? "Fixed!" : "Fix it!";
            PrefMatch("KillF1Help", isFixed ? "yes" : "no", which.child(islabel));
        }

        private void F1FixerBtnDot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (regStuff.F1HelpActive())
            {
                prefs.SetPref("KillF1Help", "no");
                regStuff.RestoreF1();
                ToggleFixedButton(sender.Parent, false, "KillF1Help");
            }
            else
            {
                prefs.SetPref("KillF1Help", "yes");
                regStuff.KillF1();
                ToggleFixedButton(sender.Parent, true, "KillF1Help");
            }
        }
```

Bottom line, it doesn't seem smart to have a separate function that does the same thing for 30 controls when I should be able to do it with ONE assuming I can figure out how to send it the information it needs to access the form elements involved.

Comment: If those aren't UserControls, then they should be.

Comment: A control event will always have a sender parameter (object).  You can write one handler that is called by all the same controls, distinguishing between them through the sender parameter.  This parameter you can safely cast to the type of object that you really have.

Comment: [You keep on referring to HTML design](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69285965/7444103), when you're in a completely different UI. Don't try to *recycle* what you know about the design of a Web page, it's useless. What you want here is to build a UserControl (as suggested multiple times) that contains all the logic to coordinate the child Controls it contains and use events (primarily) and/or public Properties / Methods to notify external interested parties of internal changes / events. Then, you can show your UserControls in a TableLayoutPanel or FlowLayoutPanel without any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the way that a FixIt button changes when you click on it, a property of your Form, or is it a property of your Button? If you decide that all your FixIt buttons should turn Blue, would that mean that the code on your Form should change?

My advice would be to create a class FixitButton:

```
class FixitButton : UserControl
{
    ...
}
```

You could derive the FixitButton from Button, but are you sure that you want to expose all properties of a Button to the users of a FixitButton? This way, users of FixitButtons can change the behaviour, such that one FixitButton will behave differently from another, which is probably not what you want.

In the FixitButton class, you can write the event handlers for click events, and let them do the changing of the layout. Also create an event to inform users of the FixitButton that it is clicked, or maybe that it changed state:

```
public bool IsSwitchedOn {get; set;}

public event EventHandler IsSwitchedOnChanged;

protected virtual void OnIsSwitchedOnChanged()
{
    this.IsSwitchedOnChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

In the method where you handle the click event:

```
... // do the changing of the layout, colours, etc
this.IsSwitchedOn = ...
this.OnIsSwitchedOnChanged();
```

Consider to let the property OnIsSwitchedOn call the Changed method:

```
private bool isSwitchedOn = false;

public bool IsSwitchedOn
{
    get => this.isSwitchedOn;
    set => if (this.IsSwitchedOn != value)
    {
        this.isSwitchedOn = value;
        this.IsSwitchedOnChanged();
    }
}
```

`OnIsSwitchedOnChanged` is defined protected virtual, so derived classes can decide to do something extra if needed.

Your form will subscribe to the IsSwitchedOnChanged event for all FixitButtons that it is interested in. They can all use the same event handler:

```
IEnumerable<FixitButton> fixitButtonsToReactOn = ...
foreach (FixitButton button in fixitButtonsToReactOn)
{
    button.IsSwitchedOnChanged = this.FixitButtonStateChanged;
}
```

And the event handler:

```
private void FixitButtonStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FixitButton changedButton = (FixitButton)sender;
    bool state = changedButton.IsSwitchedOn;

    this.ProcessChangedButtonState(changedButton, state);
}
```

So your form doesn't know anything about coloring, backgrounds etc. That is the task of the FixitButton class. If you change that class, all FixitButtons on all Forms in your application will change behaviour.

All that `ProcessChangedButtonState` has to do, is determine which button has changed state, and act accordingly.

Comment: This is probably the way. For now I'm using a form.Controls.Find(NAME OF CONTROL) method to get the right objects and I'm sure it's inelegant, but it works and building a custom control will take some time to figure out. I'll mark it as the answer regardless and get around to it eventually.

Answer (score 2):

The typical c# way would be to [create a custom control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/developing-custom-windows-forms-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) for your custom button.

That way you can put whatever custom logic to change the color and other properties in your custom control.

It might be possible to use a combination of [is operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/is), [.Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controls?view=net-5.0), and [.OfType()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=net-5.0) to traverse the tree of controls and do what you desire. But I would not recommend it since it makes your button much harder to reuse in other controls.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you're just working with Buttons and Panels.

Look at the Properties tab of the designer for your controls and notice the Tag property. You can populate these with your keys F1, F2, F3 etc. Do this for both the Buttons and the Panels to associate them.

Then handle all the Click events of the Buttons with a single method and use code such as this to get the associated panel for the event;

```
var panelOfInterest = Parent.Controls.OfType<Panel>().Single(c => c.Tag == sender.Tag);
```

If the associated controls do not share an immediate Parent then you will need to specify some other control to search through.